# How do I create an authenticated DriveService in a .NET Web App?

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to figure out the Google Drive SDK, but I can't create an authenticated DriveService object. The code Google provides is invalid and fails to compile, so it isn't of much use to me. How can I create an authenticated DriveService object in a .NET (C#) Web App? Can I do this if I already have the necessary oauth tokens and secrets in string form?

Comment: Where in the sample code did you fail? Could you provide further debug data? That would be the fastest way to fix your problem, I guess.

Comment: The sample code works for me. Include sample code and your compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently deployed a couple of VB.Net projects that use the Drive API.
One is a Web App and the user can access his/her files and the auth code is 80% from the sample app.
The other one is a service that check files on a shared folder of one account, so we had to tweak the code a little to use refresh tokens instead of auth tokens.

Take a look at the [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) page for additional informations on how to store refresh tokens for authenticated clients.

Please provide sample code so that the community can help you identify the solution in detail.

Comment: I don't have a code sample because I don't know what to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the code a bit, this one should work:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/17344396/2300810